# a good hash function to generate same hash for same text contents but different order?

Tags: hash, hashcode

if i have a block of text as follows:

```
mkdir a
mkdir b
mkdir c
```

and I would like to have a hash function which generates the same hash even if the order of text/characters change (shown below).

```
mkdir b
mkdir a
mkdir c
```

The easy approach is to sort the characters and hash it using a standard hash function. are there any other ways of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The output of a hash function changes every time you change the input, so u can't get 2 hash equals unless you get a hash collision. The probability of this collision is 1/2^nBitsHash so almost impossible.
Yes if you want to hash to be equal just do what you suggest, "The easy approach is to sort the characters and hash it using a standard hash function."

Example SHA256:
Input:

```
 mkdir a
 mkdir b
 mkdir c
```

Output: a3d9ec07503bfa1d5013df3bb185dacbebf6136ac50195979bc885c0cbbef996
Input:

```
mkdir b
mkdir a
mkdir c
```

Output: d20bea3fe4cb9e2e487bf32ec692bfd21b8d8e0cbfc2ea69ca849297fd183286